# Importing data to sqlite

Tags: sql, csv, import, sqlite

Somebody, please help me, because my head going to explode.

I'm trying to import data in sqlite3. I have `promos.sql` and `promos.csv` files. I've tried to run this in the sqlite shell:

```
.read promos.sql
```

Or do this at a unix prompt:

```
sqlite3 development.sqlite3<promos.sqlite3
```

and each time I get error

```
Error: near line 1: near ",": syntax error  
Error: near line 18: near ",": syntax error e.t.c.
```

In file are following rows:

```
INSERT INTO promos (name, promo_type, category, phone, email, message, created_at)  VALUES  
('John', 1, 3, '+111 11 111 111 11', 'some@email.com', 'Some message', '2009-09-24 12:17:17'),etc
```

so, it complains on error in each line where goes columns enumeration.

If I try

```
.import promos.csv promos
```

it says:

```
Error: promos.csv line 1: expected 9 columns of data but found 1
```

but in file are 9 columns as expected:

```
"13","John","1","3","+111 11 111 111 11","some@email.com","Some message","2009-09-24 15:17:17", "2009-09-24 15:17:17"
```

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sql problem: do you have commas at the end of your INSERT statments instead of semicolons like you should have? Please post several lines of your sql file that you're trying to run, and also post the CREATE TABLE statement for `promos`.

For the csv problem: sqlite uses | as the default separator, so you'll have to set it to use comma. Furthermore, sqlite import doesn't recognise quoted columns so if you'll have commas in your data you're best using a different method to import the data. See [this article](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You've got me a right idea. Originally I've used sentece like `INSERT INTO tbl_name (col_A,col_B) VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9);` but seems sqlite doesn't support this format. So I've made new SQL-file with separate queries for each record, and it works.

Comment: yeah, SQL generally doesn't support that syntax. You either need separate INSERT statements or you can do something like `INSERT INTO mytable SELECT 'aValue', 'another value' UNION SELECT '2nd row', 'some value' UNION SELECT 'this is the 3rd row', 'xxx'` ...